# Difficulty understanding the following function structures

Tags: javascript

Hi everyone I'm having difficulty understanding the following function structures.

Could somebody walk me through it please? I'm doing it as part of my JS course.

I have tested the functions and have seen the output but I'm not sure how JS comes to that conclusion.

Thanks in advance.

// Number 1

```
function doit(m){
    return(m+2);
}
function ask(n){
    return(n+doit(n+1)+n);
}
alert(ask(2));
```

// Number 2

```
function doit(n){
    return(n+1);
}
function ask(p,q){
    return(p+doit(q+2)+q);
}
alert(ask(2,3));
```

I am not sure how to read it!

Comment: What exactly are you having difficulty understanding in this? These aren't nested functions, and we won't just do your homework for you...

Comment: What exactly don't you understand?

Comment: How JS gives me a value of 9 for Number 1 and 11 for Number 2 - I'm trying to read the code.

Comment: Try: http://jsfiddle.net/FhQJw/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
function doit(m){
    return(m+2);
}
function ask(n){
    return(n+doit(n+1)+n);
}
ask(2);
```

`ask` is a function that takes one parameter and does the following

- add n to it. `+n` at the end.
- adds the return value of `doIt(n+1)` to it.

Thus we have `n + n + doIt(n+1)`

Now `doIt` is another function that takes a value and returns it's but incremented twice.

This gives us a total of `n + n + n + 1 + 2` Which is `3*(n+1)`

Example two is left as an exercise for the reader

Comment: Hence m is ignored completely?

Comment: @methuselah - no. The functions aren't "nested", they are just functions. *m* is a formal parameter for *doit*, it is assigned the value 3 when called from within *ask*.

Answer (score 1):

I'll go through one of them for you.

```
> function doit(n){
>    return(n+1);
> }
> function ask(p,q){   
>    return(p+doit(q+2)+q);
> }
> alert(ask(2,3));
```

The two function declarations are processed first, then the code is executed. *alert* shows a dialogue with the result of the expression passed to it between the brackets.
The bit in brackets calls the *ask* function and passes it two values: the numbers 2 and 3.

The *ask* function assigns the parameters in order: p is assigned the value 2 and q is assigned the value 3.

The line:

```
return(p+doit(q+2)+q);
```

can be written more clearly as follows (the outer brackets are redundant and a bit of whitespace makes it easier to read):

```
return p + doit(q + 2) + q;
```

It returns value the expression after the keyword *return* to the caller (*alert*), which is the value of p plus the value of `doit(q + 2)` plust the value of q.

The function *doit* is passed the value `q + 2`, which (since q was assigned the value 3) is 5.

The first value passed to *doit* is assigned to the variable n, and the value `n + 1` is returned (i.e. 6 in this case).

So now the return statement in *ask* is `2 + 6 + 3`, which is 11.

Finally, 11 is returned to *alert* and displayed on the screen.